# varnish and http header

Tags: varnish

I'm a newbie to Varnish , and I wanted to know if Varnish supports caching with http header.
We designed a Rest base web service , and I'm thinking about using Varnish to cache the results . 
How ever some of the request information (apikey) is passed via http header and I wanted to know if we Varnish can take it into account when examine the incoming request (vs query string) .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can. How should this API key be taken into account? If you want unique cache entries for every user, cache is only used if a specific user requests the same data more than once. You could get a long way without using a caching proxy like varnish by setting up the correct Cache-Control HTTP Response headers (although data freshness is not revalidated).

There are at least two approaches for this in Varnish;

1. Let your application return a HTTP-Response header *Vary: apikey* .This instructs any HTTP level cache (like varnish) to only reuse a cache result if the apikey request headers are the same.
2. Or, more efficiently, modify the vcl_hash function in your vcl config to take the apikey header into account.

   > sub vcl_hash {
   >       set req.hash += req.http.apikey; 
   >   }

Comment: Why do you consider the vcl_hash change to be more efficient than the Vary header? I would think the 'Vary: apikey' header option is a better choice, since it will work with any intermediary caches and does not rely on Varnish 'magic' that's hidden from you application logic.

Comment: Hash/Key lookup is O(1) and Vary header lookup is O(n), where n is the number of different api keys. If you have many different cache entries with the same hash, you have to consider each entry and check if all it's Vary-headers match with the current request. This could be inefficient if you have many different api keys, and only few cache-keys/responses. Check the code in bin/varnishd/cache_vary.c, in method VRY_Match.

Comment: For #2, you also need to `return (hash);` at the end of your `vcl_recv` to avoid the default logic that will by default `pass` all requests with `Authorization` or `Cookie` headers.